# Indent text left and right

Tags: html, css

I am using the `p tag` to align text left and right on the same line using:

```
.left
{
    float: left;
    text-indent: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.right
{
    float: right;
    text-indent: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

<div id="content">

    <p class="left">Left Text </p>

    <p class="right">Right Text </p>

</div>
```

The left text will indent by 5 pixels, the right text will not. I have tried -5px and just 5px, any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Read, especially the first and perhaps also the differences to the second and third: 
1] http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/text-indent/
2] http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/margin/
3] http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/padding/
 - also, you can see the effect of indentation on the first paragraph of this page: 4] http://www.htmldog.com/examples/textalign.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `margin-left` and `margin-right` instead. Or `padding-left` and `padding-right` depending on your desired output/requirement.

Comment: That's **not** indent though. Indent changes the first line only - see @nikc

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .left
    {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    .right
    {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
    #content
    {
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="left">Left Text </div>

        <div class="right">Right Text </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure `text-indent` is what your're looking for. Just to clarify: `text-indent` will indent the first row of the paragraph. Indentation is always on the left side, as long as (text-)`direction` is `ltr`, otherwise of course on the right side. All following rows will start at the boundaries of the paragraph block.

If you want to "indent" the whole block, you're looking for either `margin` or `padding`.

Also, you're not giving the floated paragraphs a width, so they will adapt to their contents, which might be the cause of you not seeing any indentation happening.

Edit: An example. Take a look at this in a browser. Then remove the `text-indent` to see what happens. As you will notice, it does work as it should, but not as you expect it to. (Or, that is, if I have understood what you're going after.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .col {
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            text-indent: 5px;
        }
        .col-left {

        }
        .col-right {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p class="col col-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

    <p class="col col-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1. Please put some more content in the paragraphs (or set width) so OP and others see the difference between `indent` and margin/padding. :)